# Mining and not seeing anything so for at 500H/s

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, cpu-mining

I am a Pastor running one GUI wallet synced on two different Dual Xeon Graphics machines and get approximately a combined hashrate avg between them of 425-525 H/s, 117-127 on an 8 core, and 335-375 from a 12-core. But I look at logs and I've been mining with rough avg of 500 H/s now, for almost 48 straight hours, well over 60 blocks have come and gone, since I synced and began mining...yet, no change in balance. I intend to use this to help others, but I am not so sure everything is being done right, wallets are syncedd to current blocks, and continue to be, but I realy have no idea how I might check to see if I just need to set it and forget it....Please Help for the Love of God.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the GUI to mine, what's happening is the GUI is basically sending a message to its daemon to say "hey, this is my wallet address, please start mining, and then if you find a block, please pay the block reward to that wallet address."

That's fine, but note that you are solo mining.  Mining rewards are only issued to a miner that solves a block.  In a pool, pooled resources add hash power to increase the likelihood of finding a block.  If a pool finds a block, it shares the block reward with the pool miners (generally minus a fee).  In your case, you'll keep the entire block reward if you find a block, but your hash rate is very low compared to the network hash rate, so it will be very, very, very seldom that you find a block.

Assuming a network hash rate of 500 MH/s, and with your 500 H/s, you should statistically win 0.0001% of the time.  There are 720 blocks mined per day, so you'd win .00072 blocks/day.  This basically means you would win an actual block of your own every 1,400 days or so.  So if the network hash rate were 250 MH/s, then you'd only have to wait, on average, 700 days for a block.

Considering that you may not want to play the lottery for several years before accumulating any winnings at all, you may want to use a pool mining software like xmrig or xmrstak, among possible others, and then mine on a pool.